# Find supremum for error bound in midpoint approximation

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

For example take the derivation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326771/derive-the-error-for-the-midpoint-rule), the answer uses Taylor expansion up to second order, but this does not guarantee that we are selecting the smallest number of slices possible right?, because why can't we just select higher order expansion and arrive with a more precise number of slices, is my reasoning correct?, here is a [backup reference](http://mx.nthu.edu.tw/%7Eychuang2/2014%20Spring/Trapezoidal%20Rule.pdf) which notes that for trapezoid rule if second order derivative bound is not known a more rough upper bound error can be given with just the first order derivate(which of course will require a larger number of slices).
Additionally can you please provide some good books/reference to read about this kind of nuances.

To make a point I will demonstrate a simple example of integrating $f(x) = e^{-10x^2}$, where $x \in [-1, 3]$ with 2 methods. First, Mathematica for reference so we can compute the error, then midpoints rule with $n$ chosen by a desired $\epsilon$, let's say $\epsilon = 1e-6$
$$ n \ge \sqrt{\frac{C}{\epsilon}}$$
where $C = \frac{|f''(\xi)|(b-a)^3}{24}$, so with Mathematica we have
$$\int_{-1}^{3}e^{-10x^2} \approx 0.5604969513265392... $$
which is correct to all the digits which are shown which is far more than enough for our analysis , and with midpoint approximation we have to choose $n \ge 7303 $, easy to calculate since $|f''(\xi)|\le 20$
$$\int_{-1}^{3}e^{-10x^2} \approx 0.560496951337889... $$
where the error is of the order $1e-11$ which is far more than the required, and by experimenting i found that even $n=100$ is sufficient to get an error $\epsilon \le 1e-6$, with $n=100$ we have
$$\int_{-1}^{3}e^{-10x^2} \approx 0.5604970109095022... $$
I think the reason here is that we are taking a limited order of Taylor expansion, but is there at least any reasoning behind why the literature uses second order expansion and not higher or lower?

In essence my question is how we derive a better (lower) error bound approximation, and please provide an example on how to get the lowest possible number of intervals in this case, Thank you

Comment: Sorry, what is exactly your question? Higher order methods are also used. They have both advantages (you need less points) and disadvantages (you often need bigger coefficients, thus increasing numerical error; also, you need more computations per point).

Comment: @mihaild it's not about the method, it's about using higher order taylor polynomial for the error bound estimation ..., read my question carefully