Continuity of second derivative in proofs of the midpoint rule remainder term?
Taylor's theorem with the remainder in Lagrange form requires the function to have $n$ continuous derivatives and an $(n + 1)$-th derivative to exist (not necessary to be continuous). This is the statement of the theorem. For example, the proofs provided by Tom Mike Apostol, "OpenStax Calculus 2" (to which Gilbert Strang is a major contributor, as far as I know) and by Vladimir A. Zorich I've read, proved strictly this statement. They aren't  assume that this derivative should be continuous.
Currently, I am exploring proofs for the remainder term of the Midpoint Rule, a method of numerical integration. The Midpoint Rule states that the error of approximation occurring when using this method can be bounded from above using the following remainder term:
$$M_n \leq \frac{M (b-a)^3}{24 n^2}$$
where $M$ is the maximum value of second derivative $|f''(x)|$, of the function being integrated.
Theorem 3.5 here: https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/3-6-numerical-integration i.e.:

The statement of the theorem assumes only the existence of the second derivative, nothing about continuity.
I've found a couple of proofs for this theorem:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327333/861268
https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~rimmer/math104/midpoint.pdf
https://www.macmillanlearning.com/studentresources/highschool/mathematics/rogawskiapet2e/additional_proofs/error_bounds_proof_for_numerical_integration.pdf

All of these proofs rely on Taylor's approximation with Lagrange form of the remainder. These proofs assume that the second derivative of the function (which is Lagrange's remainder in all these cases) is continuous. There is no contradiction with the Taylor-Lagrange remainder theorem, as far as I understand it. For as long as the $(n + 1)$th derivative exists, we can say that it's continuous.
But the Midpoint Rule assume second derivative to only exist. Why are the proofs of The Midpoint Rule, which assume the second derivative to be continuous, considered correct?

Your title is unnecessarily provocative and uninformative. Why not title the question something like "Continuity of second derivative in proofs of the midpoint rule remainder term"?

@AlexKruckman you're right. I'm going to change it to this

It looks like all the proofs only use the Lagrange remainder for $n=1$. They assume the existence of the second derivative (which need not be continuous), bound the error of the first order Taylor polynomial in terms of the second derivative, and sum over all the segments in the interval $(a, b)$. All the values of $f''$ are bounded by $M$ by definition, regardless of continuity of $f''$.
I guess there is an additional assumption that there exists a bound $M$ for $f''$ on the interval. This does not follow from the existence of $f''$; it can be unbounded. The statement "If $M$ is the maximum value of $|f''(x)|$..." should be read as an implicit hypothesis, instead of just a statement that names a variable.

I've thought of a potential point of confusion here. In your first link, the integral contains a term $\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_{i}(x))(x-c_i)^2 dx$. This is integrable because $\xi_{i}(x)$ is just a constant in $x$, so $f''(\xi(x))$ is also a constant in $x$, and constants can always be integrated over an interval. This integral makes sense as long as $f''$ is defined.
In contrast, an integral $\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(x-c_i)^2 dx$, where we actually integrate $f''$ over all its values, is not guaranteed to be defined only assuming that $f''$ exists. We would want an additional assumption like continuity to make it so that this integral exists.

All the proofs say that the second derivative is continuous (for the sake of proof). Proof by the first link saying this explicitly. They use the continuity of the second derivative to ensure that certain integral expressions are well defined and manageable.

I think without this we won't be able to move $f(\xi)$ out of integral sign as constant.

To move $f''(\xi)$ out of the integral sign, one just has to bound it as $\leq M$ and then move the $M$ out as a constant. The first link only uses $f \in C^2$ in the footnote, in order to use the intermediate value theorem on $f''$ to replace $M$ with $f''(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in (a, b)$.
In fact the intermediate value theorem always applies to $f''$ even if it is not continuous (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). So the continuity of $f''$ is not needed even for that result.

To be clear, the result in the link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327333/861268  is different from what the image in your original post says, because $M$ is replaced by $f''(\xi)$.

I've added some extra explanation that hopefully clears up some confusion.

Thanks for your patience and extra explanation. About that the $\xi_i(x)$ is just a constant in $x$ I saw a comment to the answer we are talking about that the $\xi_i(x)$ is actually depends on $x$ so $\xi$ will be different for every $x$. Author said this in 5th from bottom commentary.

I see, I hadn't read that comment before. It looks like the author of that post derived the equation by integrating a second order series at each point instead of using the Lagrange form. The same equation is valid as a direct result of the Lagrange form of the remainder only assuming that $f''$ exists, because the Lagrange form only uses one constant $\xi$ for each interval.
